# User Authentication like Instapaper or Pocket

Tags: authentication, cookies, firebase

I have a personal project that I've been using for a couple years but I've recently decided to make it publicly accessible; its very similar to [Instapaper](http://instapaper.com) or [Pocket](http://getpocket.com).

I use Firebase for user authentication (and as my database). I created a bookmarklet: when clicked it adds the Firebase script to the page and then saves info about the page to the database.

However the problem I am having is: it doesn't work on pages outside of my project's domain, because of user authentication. The Web UI part of my project works successfully, where you can login and view all your data, but when you try to save a page outside of my project's domain it doesn't work because the user is not authenticated.

**What is a simple way to solve my problem?**

I'm thinking that the Firebase script does not have access to the *auth data* for the user because its in my project's domain and *not* in the current page's domain.

Comment: Hi, I met the same problem. did you resolve?